# How to filter a Sharepoint:ListView

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2010, spquery

In VS2010 I have a SharePoint 2010 project with an Application Page. In this simple page I have header information about an order and a **SharePoint:ListView** for the product detail. So, I just want to filter that ListView by OrderId:

```
SPWeb myWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPList lstOrderDetail = myWeb.Lists["OrderDetail"];
SPView vwOrderDetail = lstProductosPedidos.Views["ShortedForCustomer"];
lvOrderDetail.ListId = lstOrderDetail.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
lvOrderDetail.ViewId = vwOrderDetail.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
lvOrderDetail.DataBind();
```

This code show a list with all the items in the "OrderDetail" list.

I tried to do with an SPQuery, but I don't know how to associate the SPListItemCollection (the result of the query) to the SharePoint:ListView.

```
SPQuery qryOrderDetail = new SPQuery(vwOrderDetail);
qryOrderDetail.Query = string.Format(@"
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='OrderId' LookupID='True'/>
      <Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>", iOrderID);
SPListItemCollection lstOrderDetailFiltered = lstProductosPedidos.GetItems(qryOrderDetail);
```

How can I filter a SharePoint:ListView with the result of a SPQuery? I am using incorrect components?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Nice try there!

You can set the query string through the list view's `query` parameter. So given your code above you would need the following:

```
SPView vwOrderDetail = lstProductosPedidos.Views["ShortedForCustomer"];
vwOrderDetail.Query = string.Format(@"
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='OrderId' LookupID='True'/>
      <Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>", iOrderID);
vwOrderDetail.Update();
```

An example you can find here: [Using SharePoint's SPView Class and CAML as a Query Language](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31762/1954) and MSDN here: [`SPView.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.query.aspx).

Comment: It works fine, thank you. But this solution modifies the view filter for everyone, and myWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates must be enabled. I suppose there is a better solution, but for now I can go on. Thanks!

Comment: You want the view to be modified only for certain persons? You're better of creating a new view then and attaching the query to that one.

Answer (score 0):

This code running for me.

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite([Site URL]);// [Site URL] change it to your sharepoint site URL
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["shared documents"];  
SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oList.Views;

            string strViewName = "MyCustomView";

            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields =
            new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

            viewFields.Add("Name");
            viewFields.Add("Type");

            string query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Name\"/>" +
                "<Value Type=\"Text\">mysample</Value></Eq></Where>";// here you can filter your items using the selected
                                                                         item in the dropdownlist
            oViewCollection.Add(strViewName, viewFields, query, 100, true, false);

 oWeb.Update();
```